# Web API Empty List With Null Safety

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an angular controller which is do a post to a web API method. I was trying to add null safety on the ienumerable, but when I did it caused the ienumerable always to be empty.

angular call

```
$http.post(customer/DoSomething, {names: ["chris", "joe"]})
```

method

```
string DoSomething(Customer customer){...}
```

model

```
// populates IEnumerable
public class Customer
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Names {get; set;}

}

// what I want to do but IEnumerable is always empty
public class Customer
{

    private IEnumerable<string> _names;
    public IEnumerable<string> Names 
    {
         get 
         {
             return _names ?? new List<string>();
         }
         set
         {
            _names = value;
         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a constructor which will initialize your collection.

```
// populates IEnumerable
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
      this.Names = new List<string>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Names {get; set;}

}
```

It will makes sure your `Names` collection is not null.

**EDIT**

This has now been simplified with C# auto properties

```
// populates IEnumerable
public class Customer
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Names {get; set;} = new List<string>();    
}
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks for the quick response. Do you know why the other way doesn't work?

Comment: @Beastwood. Your code should work as well. But amusingly it never hits setter. very strange. Hoping someone can help us here :)

Answer (score 1):

Sameer´s answer is the best practice.

Just to point out the problem with your initial code, it was always returning a new instance of the List because you were never setting the field value.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Names 
{
     get 
     {
         if(_names == null)
              _names = new List<string>();

         return _names;
     }
     set
     {
        _names = value;
     }
}
```